# how to publish a jar to NEXUS repository

Tags: gradle, jenkins-pipeline, build.gradle

I want to build a jar out of my Gradle project and push it to the nexus repository. As part of this, I created a Jenkins file and added a task "publishing" task in build.gradle.

My Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
        environment {
        NEXUS = credentials('nexus-user')
    }   
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
        buildDiscarder logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '30', numToKeepStr: '100')
    }
    triggers { pollSCM('H/5 * * * *') }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout'){
            steps { checkout scm }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps { sh "./gradlew assemble" }
        }
        
        stage('deploy') {
             steps {                     
                 sh "gradle -Duser.home=\"$WORKSPACE\" --gradle-user-home=\"$WORKSPACE/.gradle\" -PnexusUsername=$NEXUS_USR -PnexusPassword=$NEXUS_PSW publish"
                 
            }
        }   
        
    } 
}
```

And build.gradle

```
publishing {
    publications{
        maven(MavenPublication){
            artifactId = "testApp"
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/${version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? "snapshots" : "releases"}"
            credentials {
                username = "Dont know how to pass the username here" 
                password = "Dont know how to pass the password here"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the username and password from Gradle and set here for publishing the jar to nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
publishing {
    publications{
        maven(MavenPublication){
            artifactId = "testApp"
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/${version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? "snapshots" : "releases"}"
            credentials {
                username = "nexusUsername" 
                password = "nexusPassword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```